# Crashlytics "Device states 100% In Background"

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Could someone clarify on a crash report, where it states "In background" does this mean that the crash occurred in the background thread or when the app was in the background?

Trying to get to the bottom of a bug only happening on some devices.

[image: Crashlytics Report Screenshot]

Comment: Which version of firebase did you use?

Answer (score 5):

This is Zubair from Fabric/Firebase.  It's the percent of times the crash occurred while the app was not active in the foreground.

Comment: can you share Firebase documents regarding this states?